# Check webcamera status

Tags: windows, video, directx, webcam, wia

I need a way to check if a specific webcamera device is currently active (used by another application, for example Skype). Is there any method in WIA, DirectX or other API to accomplish this check?

For example, I have a software which pops up when capture is started and closes automatically upon disconnection.

Comment: Won't opening the camera that is already open get you some kind of trappable error?

Comment: It probably will, but I'm looking for a way which purely monitors device usage and avoids activating the camera - there should be some sort of property or method for checking the state.